# problem with type conversion using yaml/oyaml

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I have a YAML file with the the following line:

Spots:

```
VT CODE : 0210
```

If I read this file using yaml.safe_load and dump it afterwards I get:

Spots:

```
VT Code : 136
```

I know I can mark the 0210 as string using quotes, but i like to know why yaml behaves like this.

If try:

```
print (int('0210'))
```

I get 210

So I think there must be more the a pure type conversion

Comment: 0210 and 136 are both just representations of the same number. Python treats numbers with a leading 0 as base 8 (or python 2 did, python3 raises a syntax error and requires 0o as a prefix). Are you wanting it to be a number or a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer literals starting with a zero are octal literals in YAML based [on the spec here](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2761509) and [the quick reference card here](https://yaml.org/refcard.html).

You can see [the PyYAML implementation parsing integer nodes here](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/5986257f9fc978d4a61b6e0001df554f80e565cb/lib3/yaml/constructor.py#L243-L244), if you're inclined.

As proof of sorts, here's that 136 you're seeing represented how Python represents octals, with an `0o` prefix.

```py
>>> oct(136)
'0o210'
```

Comment: Thanks, can I tell yaml to treat them as strings or int without  hacking the yaml code?

Comment: your link to spec of YAML 1.2 says `0o14` is valid integer, and [YAML 1.1 Spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/current.html#id858734) says `014` is valid integer, so maybe spec has been changed.

Comment: @Bruno Since you're using PyYAML, you certainly can override the implementation of `construct_yaml_int` in a `Constructor` subclass of your own that you can compose into a loader á la https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/master/lib3/yaml/loader.py , but be aware you're not technically parsing YAML anymore then, but your own dialect :)